# Algorithm for calculating the nearest Euclidean matrix with constraints

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

In the area of symmetrizing the atom positions of a molecule, one typically runs into the so called [Euclidean distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix) problem. After symmetrization, a symmetric distance matrix $D$'s diagonal elements are all zero and all off-diagonal elements are positive. However, this matrix is not necessarily Euclidean.

A matrix $D$ is Euclidean if there exist $n$ points:
$p_1, \dots, p_n \in \mathfrak{R}^r$ (where $r \leq n-1)$ such that

$$ d_{ij} = \lVert p_i - p_j \rVert^2 \quad(1\leq i,j\leq n)$$

This criterion is usually not fulfilled for above mentioned symmetrized molecule distance matrices.

The nearest Euclidean matrix can be derived from the original distance matrix by means of multiple algorithms. The projection algorithm or unconstrained optimization algorithms are examples.

However, I'm not aware of an algorithm that preserves additional constraints in the original matrix through the calculation of the nearest Euclidean matrix, which is an essential requirement for keeping the nature of the distance matrix of the symmetrized molecule.

To be more specific, I'm interested in an algorithm that takes a distance matrix resembling the symmetrized molecule coordinates:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & d_1 & d_2 & d_1 & d_1 & d_1 & d_3\\
d_1 & 0 & d_1 & d_1 & d_2 & d_1 & d_3\\
d_2 & d_1 & 0 & d_1 & d_1 & d_1 & d_3\\
d_1 & d_1 & d_1 & 0 & d_1 & d_2 & d_3\\
d_1 & d_2 & d_1 & d_1 & 0 & d_1 & d_3\\
d_1 & d_1 & d_1 & d_2 & d_1 & 0 & d_3\\
d_3 & d_3 & d_3 & d_3 & d_3 & d_3 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

with certain values resulting in a non-Euclidean matrix (e.g. $d_1=225$, $d_2=150$ and $d_3=90$) and calculate an Euclidean matrix of similar structure as above, but with values for $d_1$, $d_2$ and $d_3$ which are fulfilling the criterion for a Euclidean distance matrix.

Comment: How related is this to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40162/30836) of yours?

Comment: It's the same context, but now already a bit dusted...